# query to update records count based on relation and constraints

Tags: sql, postgresql

Im trying to update a column `(address_count)` on my `people` table that must have the sum of records from another table `(people_addresses)` plus some constraints.

The idea is that, the record on `people` must exist on `people_addresses` and *must be* present on at least one of the other tables (table a, table b)

```
SELECT pd.address_id, count (pd.person_id)
FROM person_addresses pd
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT a.person_id 
              FROM table_a a where a.person_id = pd.person_id)
  OR EXISTS (SELECT b.person_id 
             FROM table_b b where b.person_id = pd.person_id)
GROUP BY pd.address_id
```

With the query above, I get the expected count, for each address that fits my requirements, altough, when I try to use it on a update, I get weird results, the records that don't fit the requirements end up with wrong values on `people_count`

query im using:

```
UPDATE people d
SET people_count = (SELECT count (pd.person_id) 
                    FROM person_addresses pd
                    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT a.person_id 
                                  FROM table_a a where a.person_id = pd.person_id)
  OR EXISTS (SELECT b.person_id 
             FROM table_b b where b.person_id = pd.person_id)
  AND d.id=pd.address_id
  GROUP BY pd.address_id)
```

I get the correct result, on records that fit the requirements, but wrong values on the ones that dont fit, when I run the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your conditions:

```
WHERE EXISTS (...) OR EXISTS (...) AND d.id = pd.adress_id
```

Is actually equivalent to:

```
WHERE EXISTS (...) OR (EXISTS (...) AND d.id = pd.adress_id)
```

You need to surround the `OR` condition with parentheses to make your intent explicit:

```
WHERE (EXISTS (...) OR EXISTS (...)) AND d.id = pd.adress_id
```

Also, the `GROUP BY` clause is superfluous in the subquery. I would suggest removing it (you will get a `0` value if the subquery does not match).

Answer (score 1):

I think your `AND`/`OR` logic needs parens.  I would write this as:

```
update people p
    set people_count = (select count(*)
                        from person_addresses pd
                        where pd.person_id = p.id and
                              ( exists (select 1 from table_a a where a.person_id = pd.person_id) or
                                exists (select 1 from table_b b where b.person_id = pd.person_id)
                              )
                       );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gordon Linoff, worked like a charm. The query its way more clear now